# Prove that the following function is differentiable

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have to prove that the following function is differentiable in all its domain.

$ \ f(x,y) = xy$

What I did:

1. Chosed $P_0=(x_0, y_0)$ as an arbitrary point
2. I showed that $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(P_0) = y_o$$ and $$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(P_0)=x_0$$
3. I proved that:

$$ \lim_{(x,y) \to(x_0,y_0)} \frac{(xy)-(x_0 y_0) -y_0(x-x_0) -x_0(y-y_0)}{||(x-x_0 , y-y_0)||}=0$$

Is that enough so that the function is differentiable in all its domain?

Comment: Yes . for me it is perfect.

Comment: Do you need do it by definition? If not, $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=y$ and $\displaystyle\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=x$. Clearly, the partial are both continuous, then, $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Yes, I needed to do it by definition, but I was little bit scared if what I did was okay or not, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have indeed showed that your $f\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable at every point.
In fact, #2 is not strictly necessary, but it certainly helps you guess the derivative needed for #3.
The partial derivatives of #2 follow from #3.

Using the definition of differentiability is always a good idea.
Only computing the partial derivatives has some pitfalls, and not all students are careful enough.